# Simplification using Cauchy Schwartz Inequality

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, probability-inequalities

Can someone please help me understand how the last step in the highlighted part in the equation is arrived at? I did not get how the Cauchy Schwartz Inequality comes into play here.
The full paper is at: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.00833.pdf (Pg 17)

[image]